# "Ext.mixin.Observable#addEvents" is deprecated in Extjs 5/6

Tags: events, extjs, extjs5, extjs6

What can we use instead of `addEvents` to add an event to the extended class?

```
this.addEvents({
    "itemclick" : true
});
```

Comment: You don't, just remove calls to it. It's served no purpose since Ext 4.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since ExtJS 5.0.0 it is no longer required to call `addEvents` before fireing events. So when you upgrade to ExtJS 5 or newer just delete all calls of `addEvents` method.

[Observable ExtJS 5 docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.mixin.Observable-method-addEvents)